# microsoft sync framework phonegap

Tags: cordova, frameworks, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

In need of sync data from my mobile app to my SQL Server, Anyonewilling to help  on this ?  any piece of code or advise will help Basically , This is what I need:

Download database records from SQL  database server (using microsoft sync framework) into the SQLite >>database  ( need to find the best way of doing this )

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [Sync Framework Toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e)

there is no sync provider for SqlLite, but the toolkit has a sample for SQL Ce that you can probably retrofit to work against SqlLite.